# How to find a particular word from the matched expression?

Tags: python, regex, grouping

I have the below line :

```
/begin MEASUREMENT MSM_Struct.ANYNAME"Status ASC"
```

and I want to find out the `ANYNAME` from the line. I tried the following expression:

```
_regex_struct = re.compile(r'/begin MEASUREMENT MSM_Struct.[\w]+')
```

Using `group(0)` gives me this output:

```
/begin MEASUREMENT MSM_Struct.ANYNAME
```

How to get `ANYNAME` in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the `.` (as you need to match a literal dot, not any char), wrap the `\w+` with capturing parentheses (also, drop the redundant `[...]` round `\w`) and get the value in `m.group(1)`.

```
_regex_struct = re.compile(r'/begin\s+MEASUREMENT MSM_Struct\.(\w+)') 
m = _regex_struct.search(s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ARcRMd/2) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6Ps3Tb).

Note I used `\s+` to match 1 or more whitespaces instead of a regular space.